# How to parse google maps geocoding api Json response to get the latidude and longitude value?

Tags: javascript, json

I got following JSON result when I called google maps geocoding api,

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
         },
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now I want to get the value of lat and lng and assign to a text box, can someone please help me

Comment: `document.getElementById("id_input").value = a['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];`

Comment: undefined error.

Comment: Please post full error message, or you can even update question with what you have tried in the coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var json = {
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "1600",
                   "short_name" : "1600",
                   "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                },
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
             "geometry" : {
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : 37.4224764,
                   "lng" : -122.0842499
                },
             },
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    };
    document.getElementById("example_input_id").value = json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    document.getElementById("example_input_id2").value = json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example_input_id">
<input type="text" id="example_input_id2">
```

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
let json = '{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"1600","short_name":"1600","types":["street_number"]}],"formatted_address":"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA","geometry":{"location":{"lat":37.4224764,"lng":-122.0842499}}}],"status":"OK"}';

let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(parsedJSON.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
console.log(parsedJSON.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: I guess you are putting the JSON in the variable with the newline characters (as it is). Either minify it before storing it as a string or try to the parse the result directly from your API call.